# Assistance with RegEx in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, microsoft-word-2010, styles

I have a Word 2010 document containing a list of blocks with predifined styles.
The styles are used in another software to process these blocks.

I created the document using a wrong quickpart so all the blocks contain a wrong style in their identifier line.

Here the ID line of the blocks:

**PREFIX_111_222_SUFFIX_incrementalID:** *The title of the block*¶

The ID is incremental (001, 002, 003, ...), and the title is different for each block. For example:

- **PREFIX_111_222_SUFFIX_001:** *This is the title of #1*¶
- **PREFIX_111_222_SUFFIX_002:** *Here is title #2*¶

And the styles are:

- **PREFIX_111_222_SUFFIX_incrementalID:** has "Style1"
- *The title of the block* has "Style2"
- ¶ has style "Normal"

The problem is that ¶ should have been Sytle1 in the Quickpart!
Now I need to change all of them so that they use the correct style.

Is there a way to achieve that with Word 2010?

I quite trained using "standard" regexp (python, perl, vim, etc.), but I am totally stuck with Word.

I really need help on this one.

---

Edit: 
Here is what I tryed so far:

First I tried to match the ID.
I tried those patterns but they all fail:

- (PREFIX_111_222_SUFFIX_*>) *:
- (PREFIX_111_222_SUFFIX_*>) *:(*)(^13)

It selects 2 lines instead of just one...

My idea is to:

1. First add # to identify the areas I want to work with:

   ```
   Pattern (PREFIX_111_222_SUFFIX_*>) *:(\*)^13
   Replacement string: \1: \2###
   ```

Of course I tried many other patterns but none of them matches the whole and only the whole line.

2. Then change the style of the line:

   ```
   Pattern (###^13)
   Repl. STYLE_SOMETHING ^p
   ```

But can't get step 1 to work. So I am totally stuck.

Here is some text sample I tried with:

```
PREFIX_111_222_SUFFIX_0001: The title of the block
Subcat1: XYZ
Subcat2: XYZ

PREFIX_111_222_SUFFIX_0002: The title of the block
Subcat1: XYZ
Subcat2: XYZ
```

Sorry, for the delay I am quite overbooked those days...
Thank you again for your help!

Comment: please share what have you tried and why those doesn't work. It'd be much more easy to help then reproducing your whole issue.

Comment: Solution, however probably will need to use a stepwise approach: **1.** change the style of your whole quickpart to style1 **2.** change the style of text (without paragraph mark) to style 2 **3.** change style of prefix to style 1

Comment: @MátéJuhász: I added some details regarding my unsuccessful attempts. Sorry for the delay, I am really busy those days. Thanks for your help and suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found why I was totally lost.
I didn't checked the boxes "ignore punctuation" and "ignore spaces".
I only checked "use special characters"

Now a pattern like:

```
(PREFIX_*>):*(<*)^13
```

Is successfully accepted.

So like I said before, I used # to identify my titles so that I can apply the correct style to them with another search and replace!